# Listing a single entry by selecting ID and updating a single entry in Python

Tags: python, csv, file, text, user-input

I'm creating a program which I will run in bash/terminal. When run, the programme is supposed to prompt the user with the question "Please add user ID". After entering an ID (not index) it should display the selected ID. eg: 1 should display the whole line of **Will Smith**.

[image: file.txt]

The code I had implemented is as below but it displays the index. If I select 1, it would display the line of **Jane Doe**. Where am I going wrong?:

```
def show_single_user():
    initialise = []
    input_user_id = input("Please add user index.")
    for i, row in enumerate(open("file.txt")):
        if str(i) in input_user_id:
            initialise.append(row)

    print(initialise)
```

I have a similar issue when I want to delete a user ID, it randomly deletes a user instead of the ID requested. I don't want to delete based on index which starts at zero. Below is the code.

```
def delete_user_id():
    text_file = open("file.txt", "r")
    target_id = text_file.readlines()
    text_file.close()

    user_input = input("Add the ID to delete:")
    del target_id[1]
    new_file = open("file.txt", "w+")

# For loop iterating to delete the appropriate line
    for line in target_id:
        new_file.write(line)
    new_file.close()
    print("User ID successfully removed!")
    input("Press any key to return to main menu")
delete_user_id()
```

Thanks

Comment: In your first code snippet `str(i)` is the index of the enumeration of the lines of the file, which starts at zero, not 1. Hence if you type in 1 you're actually getting the line with index 1 which is the second line.

Comment: you may have to use `for`-loop to search row which has expected ID in first column. OR maybe load it with `pandas` and then you can work much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the ID from the file.

```py
def show_single_user():
    initialise = []
    input_user_id = input("Please add user index.")
    for line in open("file.txt"):
        id = line.split()[0]
        if id == input_user_id:
            initialise.append(row)

    print(initialise)
```

Comment: This one does work and the output is in the form: (['1\tGeoff\tOwens\t3 Moss Lane\tManchester\tM5 8JL 01384 564877\n']) 

How can I display without the tbs (\t) but with actual tab spaces? I was reading in another forum that I should use csv but that is messing my code. I really appreciate.

Comment: split the line and re-join: print('    '.join(initialise.split()))